# How to group consecutive columns of a dataframe using split function of R

Tags: r, split

Here's a short version of my large dataframe

```
>k
a b c d e f
1 3 4 5 7 8
2 1 7 9 0 3
3 2 2 5 6 9
```

I want to split in a way so that I can make separate dataframes of a,b,& c and d,e,& f like this

```
>k
$`1`
a b c 
1 3 4 
2 1 7 
3 2 2

$`2`
d e f
5 7 8
9 0 3
5 6 9
```

I tried something like this -

```
range = seq(3,6,3)
k<-split(k, cut(colnames(k), range))
```

But it doesn't work since colnames(k) has to be numeric. Any other simple idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
group <- rep(1:2, each=3)

lapply(unique(group), FUN=function(n) k[group==n])
# [[1]]
#   a b c
# 1 1 3 4
# 2 2 1 7
# 3 3 2 2
# 
# [[2]]
#   d e f
# 1 5 7 8
# 2 9 0 3
# 3 5 6 9
```